# What they're really talking about when they're talking about Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm newbie to Android development, I entered it by coincidence, and now I've a slightly good knowledge of Android development and Xamarin, but one thing that make me so confused, when I see people talking about **Xamarin.Forms**, sometimes I think they're talking about another platform not just a reference in a project.
So from your experience with Xamarin could you please elaborate on this point, and describe to a developer of 3-weeks-experience ,how does Xamarin.Forms make the development better, What make it the brightest aspect in Xamarin development?

Comment: Instead of having Android and iOS projects in Xamarin, with a common project, that implements the "front end" of each platform, it's a common "front end" projet, from my understanding, that works for all platforms.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/

Comment: You still need Android and iOS specific projects that build an APK and IPA respectively, and those projects will have some platform specific code. But you will also have another project which is shared (either shared project or PCL) that defines the user interface in Xamarin.Forms portable code.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms allows you to define one user interface, which will be available for all supported platforms. This has a few advantages:

- You don't need to know everything about each platform's UI to write an application
- The controls that come out of the box will automatically have the look-and-feel of the target platform
- If you want to use custom controls, you can write platform-specific "renderers" to adjust the look-and-feel or to improve performance

You do notice that it's a bit slower than a native UI, but I've only noticed this when switching from view to view. Also some platform-specific controls may not be available in Xamarin.Forms.

When creating a Xamarin application, you don't *have* to use Xamarin.Forms; you can also choose to use the native UI for each platform separately.

Answer (score 1):

It was very useful for a person like me who didn't know nothing about iOS application development. I had experience building android apps but nothing for iOS, but using this I can build iOS applications too.

Using Xamarin Forms allows you to design using C# code or Xaml. If you get to know Xaml it's really easy and awesome to make designs quickly. Though you don't have an advantage of viewing the output as you build but still we hope to get it soon.

Using Xamarin Forms you don't have to worry about the native look. Xamarin maintains that beautifully. By just using the controls provided you can make the most native app in all the supported frameworks.

The other advantage as everyone says, code once and get your app ready in other platforms.

Also if you want anything not available in Xamarin Forms then you can use Renderers to do that. If you want to use some platform specific code then that can be used directly as `__IOS__`... blocks in Shared and for PCL you create Dependency Services.

About the application performance you may notice a little lag, or the increasing of application size but these things can be taken care off and there are solutions available. But if you get all these benefits then I would certainly give it a try. These are my thoughts though, you will get good answers on advantages of Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Forms allows you to create one *C# Solution / Application* that will run on Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

When you create a new application, 4 projects will be created - one for Android, one for iOS, one for WinPhone, and one Portable or Shared project.  Any code that can be shared will live in the Portable project, which will include any model definition, business logic, and much of the UI.  Each of the platform specific projects contains code to start the application on that platform, load the Forms components, and call into the Portable project.  The platform specific projects can also contain code that is specific to that platform and not supported by Forms. Two examples are functions to read/write to the device, and a 'custom renderer' of the WebView object (a Forms object) that allows setting the UserAgent string.

The code can be tested and compiled for each platform by setting that platform's project as the 'Startup Project'.  The Portable code will be compiled into the appropriate language for the platform set as the Startup Project.  So you will end up with (up to) 3 different platform-specific applications from one code base.